# Antd button loading spin centering

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, antd

Hello everyone I am using antd in my React app and have encountered a spinner problem. I would like the spinner to spin inside the element (in the center), and not stretch it, but just appear and disappear. Please help!

```
      <Button
        **loading**
        type="primary"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Click me
      </Button>
```

[standart spinner behavior][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R62gE.gif

Comment: This is the design of the antd button, i wonder whehter this is what you want? https://stackblitz.com/edit/leeklaus-btn-loading-center?file=index.js

Comment: Yes, I want the spinner to spin in the center of the element, but at the same time the inscription Loading or Click me (in my case) remained. That is, I just want to move the spinner to the center

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you want like this? the loading just center and Loading remained

Comment: you can reset the style of the loading svg component,

Comment: Can you give me the finished css code, please?

Comment: change the loading svg,  { position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); }

Comment: you use less or sass? refer to this ----->>>> https://ant.design/docs/react/faq#How-do-I-modify-Menu/Button(etc.)'s-style